# Google Maps. How change icon after click

Tags: icons, click, maps

Wrote the following code:

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 // Delete all markers.
 map.clearOverlays();

 jQuery(points_array).each(function(i, point) { 
   map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point.coord, {icon : myIcon}));
 });

 map.addOverlay(new GMarker(marker.getLatLng(), {icon : activeIcon}));
 map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
```

});

But he is not working properly. And like all logical. Remove all tags. Put a scratch. And add the one with the other icon.

Tell me, what I'm doing is wrong. And is there some other, simpler ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
var markerHighlight = new google.maps.MarkerImage(site_hUrl, new google.maps.Size(32, 36));


 marker.addListener('click', function(marker) {
      marker.setIcon(markerHighlight);
}
```

Where site_hUrl is the url of the new icon you wish to replace.
Thats all.